# How to log all the errors on exception in C# and then show?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I've written some code, in C# windows forms, binded to validation button.
The code is here: [my validation button](http://snipt.org/xogN). The code is checking validation of an XML file with XSD schema. If exception occurs then it throws the exception text into textbox and program is stopping validation.
I'd like to log the errors/exceptions into something like an array and then print the errors into the textbox.
How to do it?

```
private void validateButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    resultTextBox.Text = String.Empty;
    if (ValidateForm())
    {
        try
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemaSet.Add(String.Empty, XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(xmlSchemaFileTextBox.Text)));

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas = schemaSet;
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXmlTextBox.Text), settings);

            while (reader.Read()) { }

            resultTextBox.Text = "The XML file is OK :)" +
                Environment.NewLine +
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaException schemaEx)
        {
            resultTextBox.Text = "The XML file is invalid:" +
                Environment.NewLine +
                schemaEx.LineNumber +
                ": " +
                schemaEx.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            resultTextBox.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(null, "You have to load XML and XSD files to validate.", "There's XML file reading error.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the exception to your application's user, you can use `ExceptionMessageBox`.

```
try {
  throw new ApplicationException("test");
}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{   
  ExceptionMessageBox box = new ExceptionMessageBox(ex);
  box.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: You can create the message text to display by reading the Message and StackTrace properties of Exception and possibly InnerException, if you want to create your own text.

Answer (score 0):

you should open the `XmlReader` with the `XmlReaderSettings` object and use the `ValidationEventHandler` to catch errors and report them to the user.

see full documentation and working example at: [XmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationeventhandler.aspx)

basically write something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.IO;

public class ValidXSD {

  public static void Main() {

    // Set the validation settings.
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler (ValidationCallBack);

    // Create the XmlReader object.
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("inlineSchema.xml", settings);

    // Parse the file. 
    while (reader.Read());

  }

  // Display any warnings or errors.
  private static void ValidationCallBack (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) {
     if (args.Severity==XmlSeverityType.Warning)
       Console.WriteLine("\tWarning: Matching schema not found.  No validation occurred." + args.Message);
     else
        Console.WriteLine("\tValidation error: " + args.Message);

  }  
}
```

Comment: it started sending me notifications that XML is valid while it's invalid ;>